# Whats the URL length limit for SharePoint 2013 REST GET requests?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, url

Whats the URL length limit for SharePoint 2013 REST GET requests?

I found this

http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28494568/What-is-the-max-limit-for-URL's-with-users-using-IE-11-and-SharePoint-2013.html

But I just wanted to confirm again that its 2,083 characters.

Answer (score 5):

it is still same for IE11 and SharePoint 2013

> WinINET.h defines INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH as 2083 characters, and this
>   limit remains in force in a number of places.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/08/13/url-length-limits-in-internet-explorer.aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208427

Comment: When I try pasting in browser, the link gets cut off at 2047.

Comment: check the 2nd link to  KB article.If you are using the GET method, you are limited to a maximum of 2,048 characters, minus the number of characters in the actual path.

Comment: That says 2048, but the most I could enter was 2047...

Comment: i am not sure, but i will count this towards margin of error :)