# How to use SharePoint online rest API with large number of filter conditions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to retrieve data from SharePoint Online list using rest api (via power automate). I'm using multiple filter conditions on the same column (around 80 filter queries). When I try to execute the rest API in power automate in fails with below error message:

[image]

When I try the query in browser, I get the below error:

[image]

How can I handle this scenario?

Thanks,
Robin

Comment: Any reason to use so many filter queries in single API call? There might be some limitation with no. of characters allowed in API call endpoint. check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194576/url-request-length-limit-when-using-rest-apis and https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169973/whats-the-url-length-limit-for-sharepoint-2013-rest-get-requests

Answer (score 0):

When you have a large number of filter conditions in a REST API call, it can cause the query to become very long and potentially exceed the maximum URL length allowed by the server. This can result in a "site can't be reached" error.

To handle this scenario, you can try following solutions:

- Split the filter conditions into multiple REST API calls. Instead of including all 80 filter conditions in a single query, you can split them into smaller groups and execute multiple REST API calls to retrieve the data.
- Use indexing on the SharePoint list. If your list has a large number of items, using indexing on the column you are filtering on can improve query performance and potentially prevent the "site can't be reached" error.
- Consider using the SharePoint Search API as an alternative to the REST API, especially when dealing with complex queries with a large number of filter conditions. The SharePoint Search API can deliver more precise results than the REST API in certain scenarios. However, the implementation of the SharePoint Search API using Power Automate may require further exploration

Comment: Hi @pradip, thank you for the suggestions. Will try the first one and let you know how it turns out. Thanks.